# How to properly use command substitution in a select loop

Tags: bash, shell

The purpose of the script is to act as a directory navigator. Currently, I''m trying to print all the directories within the current directory using the fourth arguement in the select loop. I understand that I need to use command substitution but do not understand how to properly implement the backticks.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo"###################################################################"

pwd | ls -l


#problem with bad substitution below inbetween backticks
select choice in quit back jump ${`ls -l | egrep '^d' | awk $9`};
do

        case $choice in
         "quit")
                echo "Quitting program"
                exit 0
                break
         ;;

        "back")
 cd ..
                echo "Your have gone back to the previous directory: " `pwd`
                pwd 
                ls -l
         ;;

         "jump")
                echo "Enter the directory you want to move into"
                read inputDir
 if [[ -d $inputdir ]]; then
                        cd $inputDir
                        pwd
                        ls -l
                else
                        echo "Your input is not a directory, Please enter correct Di$
                fi
                ;;

         ${ls -l | egrep '^d' | awk $9}) 
        esac
        done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this is a an invalid script. \` are deprecated and discouraged, don't use them at all, use `$( ... )` for command substitution. Using ${\` ... \`} is just invalid, unless the command really returns a valid variable name, in this case it doesnt. Always quote your variables. Not `cd $inputdir` but `cd "$inputdir"`. Also quote substitution "\` command \`". And `${ls -l | .. }` is just invalid  (syntax error: bad substitution). Probably your meant to use `"$(ls -l | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}')"`. But don't parse ls output in scripts...

Comment: Multiple problems. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should really look at using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to lint your shell scripts.

I use [`mapfile`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207) to create an array based on output. I also use [`find`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2012) instead `ls` of because it handles non-alphanumeric filenames better.

I then create an array with the output appended. There are different ways to do it, but this is most straight-forward. More information about bash arrays [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

```
#! /bin/bash


echo"###############################################################"
pwd  # Your script had a |, it doesn't do anything since ls -l, doesn't take
     # input from stdin. I seperated them, because that's probably what you want
ls -l


mapfile -t output < <(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.*' | sed -e 's/^\.\///')
choices=(quit back jump "${output[@]}")

select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $choice in
        "quit")
            echo "Quitting program"
            exit 0
            break
        ;;
        "back")
            cd ..
            echo "Your have gone back to the previous directory: $(pwd)"
            pwd
            ls -l
        ;;
        "jump")
            echo "Enter the directory you want to move into"
            read -r inputDir
            if [[ -d $inputDir ]]; then
                cd "$inputDir" || exit
                pwd
                ls -l
            else
                echo "Your input is not a directory, Please enter correct Di$"
            fi
        ;;
    esac
done
```